# Is it possible to alter binding order of a Tk/Tkinter Listbox widget <<ListboxSelect>> event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

As far as I understand, the "normal" binding events order of a Tk/Tkinter Listbox widget is (simplifying): `<ButtonPress>, <<ListboxSelect>>, <ButtonRelease>`

Is it possible to "change" the order so to have `<<ListboxSelect>>` event triggering after the `<ButtonRelease>` one?

I was trying using `bindtags` together with a custom "fake" `bind_class` for this but without getting the desired result so far...
Here's the code sample:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Listbox(root, name='custlist')
for e in range(55): l.insert(tk.END, 'L_item'+str(e))
l.pack()

l.bind('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: print("L: Click"))
l.bind('<ButtonRelease>', lambda e: print("L: ButtonRelease"))

l.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda e: print("L: post-ListboxSelect"))
l.bindtags((l.winfo_pathname(l.winfo_id()),'Listbox','post-class-bindings', '.', 'all'))
```

Can you tell me if is it possible to obtain such a thing in this way or another?
Thank you

EDIT:

Thinking of it I realize I can't get it that way 'cause I guess
`<ButtonPress>+<<ListboxSelect>>` events are somewhat "chained" in their flow while `<ButtonRelease>` is something "untied", so that I should invoke/generate the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event at the end of the `<ButtonRelease>` callback to trigger it... That might work most of the times but... That's not what I was trying to get here... (Indeed, that would be just like "moving" the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event code to the `<ButtonRelease>` callbak...)
So, in the end, the question would be if is it possible to "chain" ButtonRelease together with ListboxSelect (in the same way as for ButtonPress)? ... And I guess something like that isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to "change" the order so to have `<<ListboxSelect>>` event triggering after the  one?

The only way to do that is to prevent the selection from changing on a button click. `<<ListboxSelect>>` isn't a direct result of a button click or a button release, it's a direct result of the selection having been changed. You can't have the selection change on a click and *not* have `<<ListboxSelect>>` be generated.

I don't quite understand what your real need is, but if you want to be notified of a selection change on the release of the button you can always emit your own custom virtual event in a handler for `<ButtonRelease-1>`, for instance, `<<ListboxSelectAfterClick>>`.

Comment: Hi Bryan, this is mostly out of curiosity right now tbh, as 99% of the time I managed to "solve" the things without the need of something such as changing the bindings order. The remaining 1% of the cases I felt the desire for such a thing only if the list selectmode is set to 'single'... But, even then, I usually could simply end up "reverting" the list selectmode to default without this causing or producing upheavals on the rest of the code. Thanks for your clarifications on this (your help is precious as usual), starting from them I'm able to post an answer now...

Comment: P.S. just one more question, I'm I wrong or is it emitting a custom virtual event in a handler for `<ButtonRelease-1>` (for example, `<<ListboxSelectAfterClick>>`) would be just like adding the code directly inside the `<ButtonRelease-1>` callback?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bryan Oakley's clarifications I came to a possible solution for this:

The main intent for me was to have the element
selection in the list to activate/trigger only after the mouse button being released.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Listbox(temp, name='custlist', selectmode='single')
for e in range(55): l.insert(tk.END, 'L_item'+str(e))
l.pack()

l.bind('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: "break")
def AfterReleaseSelect(event):
    event.widget.selection_clear(0,tk.END)
    event.widget.selection_set(event.widget.nearest(event.y))
    #more stuffs here if needed...
l.bind('<ButtonRelease>', AfterReleaseSelect)
```

What I'm doing here, in practice, is preventing the button click to do its job, so that the listbox selection won't be triggering, and then wait for the mouse button being released to do the stuff.

Some final thoughts on this:

First of all, please notice: I added `selectmode='single'` parameter to the Listbox widget here as I think it wouldn't be worth to apply such approach when dealing with default ("`'browse'`-select") Listboxes. This is because, differently than "'browse'-select" Listboxes, with "`'single'`-select" Listboxes elements selection doesn't "follow" the mouse 'till the end, it gets "stuck" on the first-clicked-element, even if you end releasing the mouse button on a different item.

I must say, anyhow, this probably won't be worth most of the times 'cause you might simply:

- avoid using `selectmode='single'` parameter, staying with the default listbox `'browse'`-select-behavior;
- "move" the code you would execute with a bind `<<ListboxSelect>>` to a bind on `<ButtonRelease>` (as far as this doesn't involve too much "twisting" on the rest of the code, of course...)